# sub filter or combination in html form

Tags: jquery, html

I have a issue. I am hoping I can explain this clearly. Front end is not my strong suite.

I need to create a html form search element on a list view for products

The view displays all products in the system. I need to add a filter to filter down the products

The products have applications. Lets say for this question it is A, B, C, D, E, F

Each Application can have images tied to it. The number of images can vary from 0 to n.

I want to expose the filter such that the user can select the application and also enter a number for images.

For eg:
If the user selects application A and enters number 2. Then It will return all products with Application A and which have no. of images equal to 2.
Also user can select multiple applications as well along with the no. of images tied with each.

Note: The number of images is calculated in the backend and the application is stored in the DB in a pivot table. Many to Many relationship between products and applications

If I have expose this filter to the user, how would I do it in html?

Comment: You have to write some sample HTML code first - that describes what your saying - and then try or ask for the jQuery code to do the filtering you want.

Comment: Your filter would have to work on the script side. Where are you pulling this image information from? A database? Because if that is the case, you can have the database do the filtering for you, and return the items that are then placed into the HTML. Otherwise just have to use Javascript to filter things client side